# Override Bootstrap container width when child element needs to be wider than parent

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap for responsive design and my whole site is wrapped inside `container`. The problem is that on some pages I need to have `<div>` elements 100% wide on screen. The problem is their parent `container` is of course not 100% wide so the child also cannot be. What can I do if application.html.erb looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

So, all my generated sites are inside container. That was great for me until recently. Now I run into a problem that some  elements inside generated sites need to be wider than container and I am not sure how to accomplish that. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Why would a child container need to be wider than its parent container? You might need to revisit your design, depending on what you're trying to accomplish and the exact use case, since what your essentially asking is how to fill a 1 liter bottle with 2 liters of water.

Answer (score 3):

I will post a CSS solution thats works for IE9+, althought i believe its betters to use a different layout for that case with `.container-fluid` class

```
.fullscreen-row{
   width: 100vw;
   position: relative;
   left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}

.fullscreen-row:before,
.fullscreen-row:after {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

.fullscreen-row:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a different layout for the pages that require it?

Just create a new file in layouts layouts folder. And use it when rendering in the controller.

render action: :page, layout: 'new_layout'

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution I use quite often:

```
.element-we-want-to-jump-out {
    position:relative;
    width:110%;
    /* (width - 100)/2 */
    left:-5%;
}
.parent-of-container { 
    /* can be also a body element, only condition is that it should fill out full viewport width and you will not be able to scroll horizontally inside. */
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

Note that Bootstrap container uses absolute paddings and the 10% used for overflowing might not be enough for very low viewport widths (< 300px). You can still use more and adjust your "jumping out element" (e.g. by changing background size if it is an image, or padding if it is a table etc...)